# Why specify data types but not struct in function parameters? C++

Tags: c++, struct

Writing a function in C++, to my understanding, goes like this:

```
 int  foo(int x) 
    {
    //some code
    }
```

First of all, int is the data type, why do we need to specify it?
Second of all if we have code like this:

```
  struct Monster
{
    std::string name;
    int health;

};
int printMonster(Monster myMonster)
    {

        std::cout << "This monster is named " << myMonster.name << " and has " << myMonster.health << " health" << std::endl;
        return 0;
```

Why do we write the struct name, in this case "Monster" instead of struct?

Comment: Well you don't have to, you can write `auto x` instead of `int x`

Comment: With just `struct` the compiler would not know which of the many `struct`s that have been defined to use. Your code may only define one, but odds are really good you're including a library header, and Crom only knows what it includes and declares.

Comment: "why": because that's how the language was meant – strongly, explicitly typed. Since types are necessary for thinks like overloaded functions, you can't do without.

Comment: Maybe better to ask one question at a time.

Comment: The names of the types are, respectively, `int` and `Monster`. That's why you write them in the parameter list.

Comment: @M.M But then the compiler interprets it as int, why does it need to? And also I'm really curious why the compiler won't accept struct, but instead requires the name of the struct?

Comment: @samsas It requires the types. `int` is a type. So is `Monster`.

Comment: How would the compiler know what the type was if you didn't write it?

Comment: Some sort of type inference based on the call, would be my guess. I'd hate to see what the compiler errors would look like. Templates can get hairy enough.

Comment: @user4581301 so does that mean Monster is a data type? Is it not just a name for a struct, like if int x = 1; x would be the name and int the data type.

Comment: Yup. `Monster` is your very own, self-defined  data type.

Comment: @user4581301 In that case, what purpose does the keyword struct serve?

Comment: `struct` tells the compiler you are defining your own data type.

Comment: @samsas `struct` is for a declaring a type that can be instanced, where the default access modifier for members and the default inheritance type are both public. You really should get some good learning materials if you want to learn C++, looking at and guessing the intention of code ( or worse, keywords ) is really not a good way to learn the language.

Comment: It specifies to the compiler the basic rules of how to interpret the datatype you are defining.  A `struct` is an aggregation of related data and functions. A `class` is the same thing, but with more restrictive default access. In other words, slightly different interpretation. A `union` is a bunch of variables all sharing the same space. Very different interpretation even though with the exception of one word, the definition looks exactly the same as a `struct`. An `enum` is different again, one variable with a set of valid values.

Comment: I suggest "int printMonster(Monster myMonster){...}" should be "int Monster::print(){...}" -- the method should be part of the class ... think encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question

`First of all, int is the data type, why do we need to specify it?`

In C/C++ you have to specify the data type for your variables. But you could also use the auto keyword like M.M suggested. You can use it, but I don't recommend using it cases like this.

For the second question

`Why do we write the struct name, in this case "Monster" instead of struct?`

Think about it like this. When you use the keywords `struct` or `class`, you are creating your own datatype. Monster is the datatype that you have created. Since C++ requires a data type for all variables, you write your datatype as `Monster`

Comment: I'm still trying to rationalize it in my head. Would it be correct to imply then, that Monster is a new data type created from a blueprint which is a struct?

Comment: @samsas a data type is a blueprint for instances of that data type

Comment: @samsas: `struct` just means "The next piece of code is defining a new type".  It isn't really a "blueprint".